# wxPython ScrolledWindow too small

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a panel to control editing of a matplotlib graph in a wxPython frame.  The wxPython install was recently updated to 2.8.12.1 from 2.6.4.0 and it broke a few things, namely, the scroll panel no longer fills a block but instead stays at a minimum size.  I'm just now picking this up from a year ago so I'm a bit rusty.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Below is a stripped-down version of the code that can be run on its own and displays the problem.  The ScrolledWindow should expand up to 400px.  When I run it `self.scroll.GetSize()` returns `(292, 257)` but it clearly is not displaying at that size.

```
# testing scroll panel for PlotEditFrame

import wx

# spoof the necessary matplotlib objects
class FakePlot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.figure = FakeFigure()
    def get_figure(self):
        return self.figure
class FakeFigure:
    def __init__(self):
        self.axes = [FakeAxis() for i in range(0,2)]
class FakeAxis:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = [FakeLine(i) for i in range(0, 4)]
class FakeLine:
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.label = "line #%s"%i
    def get_label(self):
        return self.label

class PlotEditFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    This class holds the frame for plot editing tools
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, plot):
        """Constructor for PlotEditFrame"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Edit Plot")
        self.parent = parent
        self.plot = plot
        self.figure = plot.get_figure()
        self.advanced_options = None
        self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1)
        self.InitControls()

    def InitControls(self):
        """Create labels and controls based on the figure's attributes"""

        # Get current axes labels
        self.lineCtrls = [( wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1, "Column:"),
                            wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1, "Color:"),
                            wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1, ""))]

        for axis in self.figure.axes:
            for line in axis.lines:
                color = wx.Colour(255,0,0,0)
                lineTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, line.get_label(), size=(175,-1))
                lineColor = wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, "#%02x%02x%02x"%color.Get())
                lineBtn = wx.Button(self.scroll, -1, size=(25,25))
                lineBtn.SetBackgroundColour(color)
                self.lineCtrls.append((lineTxt, lineColor, lineBtn))

        # Place controls
        boxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        lineBox = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "Lines")
        lineBoxSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(lineBox, wx.VERTICAL)
        lineSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=len(self.lineCtrls)+1, cols=4, vgap=3, hgap=3)
        for ctrls in self.lineCtrls:
            lineSizer.AddMany([(ctrls[0], 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.EXPAND),
                               (ctrls[1], 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT),
                               (ctrls[2], 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER| wx.FIXED_MINSIZE),
                               ((3,3),    0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)])
        lineSizer.AddGrowableCol(0)

        # Set size
        self.scroll.SetSizer(lineSizer)
        width = self.scroll.GetBestSize().width
        height = self.scroll.GetBestSize().height
        if height > 400:
            height = 400
            width = width + 25 # button size
        self.scroll.SetSize((width, height))
        self.scroll.SetScrollbars(0, 1, 1,1)
        print "set scrollbars at %s x %s"%(width, height)

        lineBoxSizer.Add(self.scroll, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        boxSizer.AddMany([ (lineBoxSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND) ])

        self.SetSizer(boxSizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.Fit()

        height = self.GetSize().GetHeight()
        self.SetSizeHints(minH=height, maxH=height,
                                minW=width, maxW=width*5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    parent = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'test', size=(300,300))
    plot = FakePlot()
    panel = PlotEditFrame(parent, plot)
    panel.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I can't figure out what panel needs resized.  Some things I've tried, to no avail:

```
# These have no visible effect
boxSizer.SetMinSize((width, height))
self.scroll.SetVirtualSize((width, height))
lineBoxSizer.Fit(self.scroll)
lineBoxSizer.SetVirtualSizeHints(self.scroll)

# This makes the window the right size, but not the scroll panel
lineBoxSizer.SetMinSize((width, height))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your code a bit to get it to work:

```
import wx

# spoof the necessary matplotlib objects
class FakePlot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.figure = FakeFigure()
    def get_figure(self):
        return self.figure
class FakeFigure:
    def __init__(self):
        self.axes = [FakeAxis() for i in range(0,2)]
class FakeAxis:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = [FakeLine(i) for i in range(0, 4)]
class FakeLine:
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.label = "line #%s"%i
    def get_label(self):
        return self.label

class PlotEditFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    This class holds the frame for plot editing tools
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, plot, size):
        """Constructor for PlotEditFrame"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Edit Plot", size=size)
        self.parent = parent
        self.plot = plot
        self.figure = plot.get_figure()
        self.advanced_options = None
        self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1)
        self.InitControls()

    def InitControls(self):
        """Create labels and controls based on the figure's attributes"""

        # Get current axes labels
        self.lineCtrls = [( wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1, "Column:"),
                            wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1, "Color:"),
                            wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1, ""))]

        for axis in self.figure.axes:
            for line in axis.lines:
                color = wx.Colour(255,0,0,0)
                lineTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, line.get_label(), size=(175,-1))
                lineColor = wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, "#%02x%02x%02x"%color.Get())
                lineBtn = wx.Button(self.scroll, -1, size=(25,25))
                lineBtn.SetBackgroundColour(color)
                self.lineCtrls.append((lineTxt, lineColor, lineBtn))

        # Place controls
        boxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        lineBox = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "Lines")
        lineBoxSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(lineBox, wx.VERTICAL)
        lineSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=len(self.lineCtrls)+1, cols=4, vgap=3, hgap=3)
        for ctrls in self.lineCtrls:
            lineSizer.AddMany([(ctrls[0], 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.EXPAND),
                               (ctrls[1], 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT),
                               (ctrls[2], 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER| wx.FIXED_MINSIZE),
                               ((3,3),    0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)])
        lineSizer.AddGrowableCol(0)

        # Set size
        self.scroll.SetSizer(lineSizer)
        width = self.scroll.GetBestSize().width
        height = self.scroll.GetBestSize().height
        if height > 400:
            height = 400
            width = width + 25 # button size
        self.scroll.SetSize((width, height))
        self.scroll.SetScrollbars(0, 1, 1,1)
        print "set scrollbars at %s x %s"%(width, height)

        lineBoxSizer.Add(self.scroll, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        boxSizer.Add(lineBoxSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(boxSizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        #self.Fit()

        height = self.GetSize().GetHeight()
        self.SetSizeHints(minH=height, maxH=height,
                                minW=width, maxW=width*5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    plot = FakePlot()
    frame = PlotEditFrame(None, plot, size=(300,300))
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The main thing was to set the proportion to "1" on the following two lines:

```
lineBoxSizer.Add(self.scroll, 1, wx.EXPAND)    
boxSizer.Add(lineBoxSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

I changed the way you start the program as it's a little silly to put a frame inside another frame for this case. Also PySimpleApp is deprecated, so I changed that too. I have almost never found a good use for the "Fit()" method, so I took that out as it was squashing the initial GUI too much.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks.  This is part of a much larger app which is why it's set up that way, but your hints got me in the right direction.  I ended up changing the proportions as you said, setting the minsize of the outermost sizer to the sum of the minsizes of the internal elements (why this wasn't automatic I have no idea), and keeping the call to `self.Fit()` to put everything in place.

Comment: I think the problem is that the size of the widget when Fit is called is still really small, so it just goes with the flow. If might work if we put the Fit() call in wx.CallAfter() so it wasn't called until right before the window is shown.